# Replace literal "\r\n" in text file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace each `\r\n` in a text file with `<p/>`.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
sed 's#\r\n#<p/>#g' test.txt
sed 's#\r\n#<p/>#g' test.txt
sed 's#/\r/\n#<p/>#g' test.txt
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/<p/>/g' test.txt
```

Here is the text in `text.txt`

```
https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/\r\nhttps://www.pivotaltracker.com/story\r\n\r\nSome business text.\r\n\r\nSome business text. Task 123 is still a work in progress but we wanted it in develop to keep everything updated.
```

Comment: Did you try `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s#\r\n#<p/>#g'`?

Comment: shouldn't i specify the file?

Comment: er, yes, I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Does the text contain literal characters `\r\n` or are you writing it like that to show us where the carriage returns and newlines are?

Comment: this is the exact text in the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the other answers have assumed that you are trying to handle Windows-style line endings and change them to paragraph tags.

To change the literal sequence of characters `\r\n` to something else, just use a global substitution:

```
sed 's!\\r\\n!<p/>!g' file
```

The `\` themselves need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file | tr -d '\r' | sed 's|$|</p>|g' | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat). `tr -d '\r' < file | ...`

Answer (score 1):

Line endings are much easier to manipulate with perl one-liners than with `sed`.  This is totally untested, but *should* work (the only question in my mind is whether perl might do universal newline handling these days, in which case you'd never see a `\r`):

```
perl -e 'undef $/; while (<>) { s:\r\n:<p/>:g; print; }' test.txt > xtest.txt
```

or equivalently

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { undef $/ } s:\r\n:<p/>:g' test.txt > xtest.txt
```

The key is `undef $/` at the beginning, which makes perl read the entire of `test.txt` as one big long string; the obvious regex then Just Works.

Comment: i have added the test from my file... when i run these the `xtest.txt` still contains the `\r\n` characters