# Bash: How do I replace literal a \r\n in a string?

Tags: bash, escaping

I am trying to replace a literal `\r\n` with a literal `\n` using `tr`

```
STR="**Line1**\r\nLine2"
echo $STR
echo $STR | tr '\r\n' '\n'
```

I would expect

```
**Line1**\r\nLine2
**Line1**\nLine2
```

But instead I get

```
**Line1**\r\nLine2
**Line1**\r\nLine2
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `\r\n` is a string of four characters. You need a tool that can replace strings like `sed`, `tr` rather performs a char-by-char transliteration.

Comment: Duplicate of [Replace \r\n in text file on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380437/replace-r-n-in-text-file-on-command-line), though OP is more clear

Answer (score 1):

`tr` replaces from stdin to stdout. To replace the variable bash parameter expansion could be used instead

```
STR=${STR//\\r\\n/\\n}
echo "$STR"
```

Also don't forget double quotes when using as parameter if string can contain tab space or newline.

Otherwise if the issue is with `tr`. backslash is an escape character an must be escaped, but `tr` is a character transliterator and isn't suitable to replace strings.